# css width % in ie7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, width

I have a parent container which is 100%. It contains 2 floating divs which are width:50%. The children contains only text. The problem is that the children on get as wide as the text, and not 50% of the width of the parent container. It is only ie7 that is a problem. Maybe also ie6, but I don't care about that browser.

```
ball (width 16px position absolute)
   parent (width 100% position absolute. Should be more than 16px)
      child (width:50% float left)
      child (width:50% float left)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Please post some HTML+CSS code

Answer (score 2):

No need for a JS hack. Just use the right [doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/http://).

Copy'n'paste'n'run this, check the result, then remove the doctype and retest in IE.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            body { width: 300px; }
            .parent { width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden; }
            .child { float: left; width: 50%; }
            h3 { clear: left; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Test 1</h3>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child">text</div>
            <div class="child">text</div>
        </div>
        <h3>Test 2</h3>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child">text text text text text text text text text text</div>
            <div class="child">text</div>
        </div>
        <h3>Test 3</h3>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child">text</div>
            <div class="child">text text text text text text text text text text</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Without doctype or with a non-standards-mode doctype IE will namely render in [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).